# RewriteRule returns HTTP 200 when it should be HTTP 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, curl, url-rewriting

The following `RewriteRule` forwards traffic from a url `shows.php?id=review-1` to a server-side controller file which creates an SEO friendly URL and further redirects using a 301 redirect. Using `CURL`, The redirect to the controller file shows as a 200, a direct link to the controller file shows a 301.

Here's my `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=review-[0-9]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /controllers/redirectseo.php? [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Here's the result of my `CURL` calls:

```
curl -I http://www.defunctgames.com/shows.php?id=review-1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -I http://www.defunctgames.com/controllers/redirectseo.php?id=review-1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to modify my `RewriteRule` to get rid of the `[QSA]`, thinking perhaps that is the issue. It still doesn't return 301. The following rewrite rule DOES return a 301, so I know it works at some level. Does the FQL make a difference perhaps?

```
RewriteRule ^defunctexplorer.htm$ http://www.defunctgames.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried a FQL redirect, and that doesn't make a difference either. Here's what I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.defunctgames.com/controllers/redirectseo.php?id=%2-%3 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution? I have applied a 301 redirect, and it seems to work but using curl it says "200 code response".

Answer (score 0):

Does `%{THE_REQUEST}` have the querystring appended, unencoded? Might be worth trying this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=review-[0-9]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /controllers/redirectseo.php? [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried removing the `\?` like you suggested, and it didn't seem to make a difference.